# Problems with dispose() commando in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, dispose

My code is:

```
    String bokstaver = Bokstaver.getText();
    String tall = Tall.getText();

    if (bokstaver.isEmpty() || bokstaver.length() < 1) {
        Bokstaver.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    if (tall.isEmpty() || tall.length() < 5) {
        Tall.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    if(tall.length() == 4 && bokstaver.length() == 1){
        //skriver inn string for registreringsnummer
        registreringsnummer = bokstaver + " " + tall;
        dispose();
    }
```

The code is written in a jButtonMouseClicked method. If I type the correct type in the two text fields, the window wont close. That is for both the first time the button is clicked, and the rest after that. If I have the dispose() outside the if - loop, it works, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give me an example of a `bokstaver` and a `tall` input you believe should call dispose.

Comment: Have you tried using a `println` debug statement to check the values, and determine which code is being executed?

Comment: your `if` statement isn't being satisfied, debug through the code and see what lengths you are getting for `tall` and `bokstaver`

Comment: Thank you, noticed what was wrong now. Was simply just the if statement that wasnt satisfied. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is not being satisfied. Make sure that:

```
tall.length() == 4
```

AND

```
bokstaver.length() == 1
```

A valid input for the `Tall JTextField` would be:

```
abcd
```

and

```
a
```

for the `Bokstaver JTextField`